# PL/SQL function error- not understandable

Tags: sql, function, plsql

I have to do a pl/sql function. I have quite done it but on the server it shows an error but I have no idea what does the error means. 
Could someone guide me into the right direction to complete the function?

This is the code:
SHOW ERRORS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_of_task_types(project project.project_no%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
task NUMBER;

    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
    INTO task
    FROM project p, stage s, task t ;
    WHERE user_input_var = p.project_no;
    AND p.project_no = s.project_no;
    AND s.stage_id = t.stage_id;
    AND p.project = project;
    RETURN  task;

    END;
    /
```

--use of the function

```
SELECT project_no, sum_of_task_types(project_no)project;
```

I do not know if the code looks clear here, so I have added a document showing the image of the code itself with the error shown below:
[image]

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_of_task_types(project project.project_no%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
task NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
INTO task
FROM project p, stage s, task t 
WHERE user_input_var = p.project_no
AND p.project_no = s.project_no
AND s.stage_id = t.stage_id
AND p.project = project
RETURN  task;

END;
/
```

I have done this now, still gives errors:

```
LINE/COL   ERROR
6/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/5    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of each **line**. The `;` only goes at the end of the _statement_.

Comment: Thank you for answering, this isn't it in my case, after deleting the ";" it gave these errors:LINE/COL ERROR
6/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/5 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Yes it **is** "your case". And you shouldn't delete **all** `;` you still need one at the end of each statement.

Comment: I have only deleted 4 of them. The code looks like this:
SHOW ERRORS
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_of_task_types(project project.project_no%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
task NUMBER;

    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
    INTO task
    FROM project p, stage s, task t 
    WHERE user_input_var = p.project_no
    AND p.project_no = s.project_no
    AND s.stage_id = t.stage_id
    AND p.project = project
    RETURN  task;

    END;
    /

Comment: **Edit** your question. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: Thank you for instructions, I didn't know how to edit but added as an answer if this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

just add a ';' after 'AND p.project = project' to indicate termination of sql statement and this will become error free.

Answer (score 0):

```
--There was a slight ';' syntactical mistake which was in the way of compiling FUNCTION correctly. I have posted below code hope it helps

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_of_task_types(
    project project.project_no%TYPE)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  task NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_type_no)
  INTO task
  FROM project p,
    stage s,
    task t
  WHERE user_input_var = p.project_no
  AND p.project_no     = s.project_no
  AND s.stage_id       = t.stage_id
  AND p.project        = project;
  RETURN task;
END;
```